# How to estimate model parameters using maximum likelihood estimation?

Tags: probability, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

I'm referring Andrew Ng machin learning course, and currently studying Gaussian Discriminant Analysis model from [this](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes2.pdf) notes.

Now I understand following model equations:

[image]

And why it's log maximum likelihood is written as following:

[image]

But what I don't understand is that how the maximization with respect to the parameters φ, Σ,μ0 and μ1 is derived or how the values of φ, Σ,μ0 and μ1 are derived?

I've already searched this but can't find the exact proof or derivation for the same. I'm not asking for the full derivation or proof, just appropriate reference with some explanation will do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Partially differentiate the log likelihood w.r.t each of the parameters and set them to zero.

Comment: But what should be the values of `x(i)` and `y(i)`, while partially differentiating them?

Comment: x(i) and y(i) are assumed to be given to you and are considered constants.

Comment: $x^{(i)}$ and $y^{(i)}$ are your data points...